# why could not found the chromedriver cask

Tags: homebrew, google

I am tried to use this command to install chromedriver in macOS 13.4 with M1 pro chip:

```
> brew install --cask chromedriver
fatal: not in a git directory
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
Warning: Cask 'chromedriver' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
==> Searching for similarly named casks...
==> Casks
homebrew/cask-versions/chromedriver-beta

To install homebrew/cask-versions/chromedriver-beta, run:
  brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/chromedriver-beta
```

the command told me to use another command to install, but I found the version was conflict with chromedriver in this website: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/chromedriver. what should I do to install the chromedriver?